# SQL Server, LIKE vs. RTRIM performance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've been given a very small sample DB and I'm wondering about performance on the main server (which I can't access).

There's a string field used as an fkey that is fixed length, but the UI is passing trimmed strings. So for now I'm doing `RTRIM(LTRIM(XREF))='thekey'`.

I'm curious if `XREF LIKE '%thetkey%'` offers any benefits? It's easier to read, but I'd like to know if there are any performance implications.

**UPDATE:** the data in the DB is like `'thiskey      '`, but the UI hands me `'thiskey'`.

Comment: Both are terrible. Trim before passing to SQL. If you meant that `xref` is `char(x)` as opposed to `varchar(x)` and as such is padded with spaces, then this is [how it is supposed to be](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316626/inf-how-sql-server-compares-strings-with-trailing-spaces), you don't need the trims.

Comment: @GSerg - yes, the xref is char(25). But the string I'm handed to look for is trimmed. So I'm not sure about your comment, can I just match with no like or trim and the padding will be ignored in the field during the compare?

Comment: The result will not always be the same, for instance the row with a value 123thekey567 will also be selected using LIKE approach and this is not what you will want

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz [`'abc' = 'abc      '`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316626/inf-how-sql-server-compares-strings-with-trailing-spaces).

Comment: Good point @AlexanderVolok! - I need more coffee.

Comment: Ok @GSerg, that's the solution then. I have never (believe it or not) worked with a char() field used as a key before, so this is new to me.

Comment: The other thing that trim approach stil can be indexed by using persisted calculated column so it can be way faster than LIKE

Comment: if the column name is char, SQL will automatically trim the spaces when doing comparison, so there is no need to RTRIM/LTRIM your column.  IE `XREF='thekey'` should work.